# Объяснить функцию, которая вычисляет день недели

Tags: c++, c++11

Нужно написать программу с функцией, которая будет вычислять день недели по дате. Даты представлены структурой (год, месяц, день).
В этой программе мне не очень понятна функция int date(Date z), а именно с 20 по 24 строку. Хочу разобраться в этой функции. Объясните, пожалуйста, эти строки.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

int date(Date z)
{
    int a;
    int y;
    int m;
    int R;
    a = (14 - z.month) / 12;
    y = z.year - a;
    m = z.month + 12 * a - 2;
    R = 7000 + (z.day + y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400 + (31 * m) / 12);
    return R % 7;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    Date z;
    char C;
    string S[7] = { "Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота" };
    cin >> z.day >> z.month >> z.year;
    cout << S[date(z)] << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Покопайтесь в Интернете/литературе, как вычисляют [юлианскую дату](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)...

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данной функции вычисляется, высокосный ли год или нет, так как каждые 14 лет, прибавляется день в феврале, то есть 29 дней, а в не высокосные годы, будет соответствено 28 дней. А возвращает она, остаток от деления в данной функции, который и будет соответствовать дню недели.
Так же отвечу для предыдущего человека, функция  '_getch()' ожидает от пользователя дальнейших действий, дабы консоль не закрылась после выполнения своей функции.

Answer (score 1):

Я попытался изъяснить принцип действия этого кода простыми словами, вот:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Создает структуру "Date" с внутренними переменными (день, месяц, год).
struct Date{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

int date(Date z){
    // Создает переменные.
    int a;
    int y;
    int m;
    int R;
    // Вычисляет непонятный для меня номер (от 14 отнимает месяц и разделяет на 12).
    a = (14 - z.month) / 12;
    // От года отнимает номер.
    y = z.year - a;
    // Вычисляет код года (к месяцу прибовляется (12 умноженное на номер), и отминусовуется 2).
    m = z.month + 12 * a - 2;
    // Вычисляет число (к 7000 прибавляется (математическое уравнение вычисления дня недели)).
    R = 7000 + (z.day + y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400 + (31 * m) / 12);
    // Возвращает номер дня недели (седьмой процент числа).
    return R % 7;
}

int main(){
    // Устанавливает язык локализации "Русский".
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    // Создает переменную даты (используя структуру "Date").
    Date z;
    // Создает список дней недели.
    string S[7] = { "Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота" };
    // Принимает (день, месяц, год).
    cin >> z.day >> z.month >> z.year;
    // Отсылает в функцию "date" внесенную дату, и принимая номер дня ворачивает название.
    cout << S[date(z)] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

У меня `_getch();` функция не работает, и я так и не понял зачем она, поэтому я её убрал.

Я вот предлагаю более оптимизированный вариант для компьютера нужно добавить библеотеку `#include <ctime>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// Создает структуру "date" с внутренними переменными (день, месяц, год).
struct date{ int day, month, year; };

int get_weekday(date i){
    // Заносит дату в переменную.
    std::tm time_in = { 0, 0, 0, i.day+1, i.month+1, i.year };
    // Конвертирует дату в time_t.
    std::time_t time_temp = std::mktime(&time_in);
    // Вносит time_t дату в переменную time_out.
    const std::tm * time_out = std::localtime(&time_temp);
    // Возрващаем из time_out день недели.
    return (int)time_out->tm_wday;
}

int main(){
    // Устанавливает язык локализации "Русский".
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    // Создает переменную даты (используя структуру "date").
    date z;
    // Создает список дней недели.
    string S[7] = { "Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота" };
    // Принимает (день, месяц, год).
    cin >> z.day >> z.month >> z.year;
    // Отсылает в функцию "get_weekday" внесенную дату, и принимая номер дня ворачивает название.
    cout << S[get_weekday(z)] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Вычисляет високосный год или нет (от 14 отнимает месяц и делит на 12)` Как по этой формуле понять високосный год или нет?  Судя по ссылке на вики про юлианский календарь, это просто коэфф.

Comment: Ой, я ошибся, он не проверяет високосный год или нет.
Я все исправил.